# Accessing EMR created in Account A and from Account B

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I have a EMR cluster in Account A and a SWF WF running in Account B. The SWF activity tries to copy data on EMR cluster.

But, the copy fails with Authentication error. Any one has some idea on what permission need to be given so that SWF running account B can copy data on EMR clsuter in account A.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to a cross-account access, basically you will need to create and IAM role in account A that can access the to your EMR cluster, and then give this IAM role to SWF in Account B.

check this link : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/delegation-cross-acct-access.html